# How to install lombok plugin in Android studio offline?

Tags: android-studio, plugins, lombok

I have an Android studio in a computer without Internet access . I want to download a file in another computer and move to my computer in order to install lombok plugin in Android studio . How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I want to clarify you that without lombok jar in local repository, you cannot run project(get lombok's taste).

### Online Mode:

For project building it is necessary to add lombok dependency in build file fon online mode.

### Offline Mode:

But if you want to use it offline, it is not necessary to declare in build file. You can add it manually.

**Image is attached below:**
[image]

Resource Link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Lombok/article.html